# xtext manuel multi-file compilation

Tags: java, xtext

I am working o a xtext grammar and i am referencing artifacts like this:
`A: 'A' name=ID;`
`B: 'B' name = ID ':' ref=[A];`
So after launching the eclipse runtime with plugin, i can create files with proper extension containing this:
`A a`
`B b : a`
Now i want to refer to artifacts from other files as well and it works out of the box:
if `A a` is declared in a.file and `B b : a` is declared in b.file the editor shows no errors. 
The auto-compile works fine as well.

However, if i generate the code on my own like this:
`generator.doGenerate(new ResourceSetImpl().getResource(URI.createURI(path), true), fsa);`
The reference is not resolved.

Do i have to compile all files in one run? How could i do this?

Answer (score 0):

The files are usually compiled by an incremental Xtext build in the background as soon as you save it. If you want to trigger the build manually, you have to make sure to use a properly initialized resource set. It can be obtained from the `IResourceSetProvider` in an Eclipse context. In standalone mode, you can inject a `Provider<XtextResourceSet>` to get a configured instance.

Comment: i am not sure if you realized, that i want to compile the dsl-files on my own (with the code i supplied). As is said, working with the eclipse plugin, everything works fine. But when i start to compile the files manuely it doesnt resolve the references to other dsl-files. The problem i want to solve: compile dsl-files without the complete "xtext-plugin-workflow" just from source code.

Comment: i injected it like this, but my resourceset is empty if i do this: val injector = new MyDslStandaloneSetup().createInjectorAndDoEMFRegistration();
val resourceSetProvider = injector.getInstance(Key.get(new TypeLiteral<Provider<XtextResourceSet>>() {}));